# Programmatically (un)register to event with Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a directive that listens to some events using the `host` property of the `@directive` decorator. This works great, but I don't need all events at all times.

For example, I'm only interested in `(document: mouseup)` at certain times (namely after a mousedown on my element).

What is the angular way to register and unregister to events dynamically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you register imperatively you can unregister the same way. AFAIK for declaratively added listeners there is no way to unregister.

```
import {DOM} from 'angular2/platform/common_dom.dart';

DOM
    .getGlobalEventTarget('window')
    .addEventListener('message', function, false);
    //.remove...
```

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6904

You could also just use

```
document.addEventListener
        // remove ...
```

but direct DOM access is discouraged. But in the comments of the linked issue they seem to see the first approach as direct DOM access as well.

Comment: Fair enough. How would I do that? Can I just use addEventListener()? I recall some $apply magic requirements in angularjs. Also, is there a $destroy equivalent? I guess I'll be needing that too.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you've seen the 'draggable' example that is available as part of some angular class. There is an adapted version of it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36290753/193050). While it doesn't exactly do what you ask - ie register and de-register mousemove depending on whether we are currently dragging or not - it is one way of doing a draggable directive in angular 2.

My own slightly more general purpose version goes like this:

```
import {Directive, EventEmitter, HostListener, Output} from 'angular2/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Directive({
  selector: '[draggable]'
})
export class DraggableDirective {

  @Output() mousedrag: Observable<{x: number, y: number}>;
  @Output() dragend = new EventEmitter<void>();
  mousedown = new EventEmitter<MouseEvent>();
  mousemove = new EventEmitter<MouseEvent>();
  dragActive = false;

  @HostListener('document:mouseup', ['$event'])
  onMouseup(event) {
    if(this.dragActive) {
      this.dragend.emit(null);
      this.dragActive = false;
    }
  }

  @HostListener('mousedown', ['$event'])
  onMousedown(event: MouseEvent) {
    this.mousedown.emit(event);
  }

  @HostListener('document:mousemove', ['$event'])
  onMousemove(event: MouseEvent) {
    if(this.dragActive) {
      this.mousemove.emit(event);
      return false;
    }
  }

  constructor() {
    this.mousedrag = this.mousedown.map((event) => {
      this.dragActive = true;
      return { x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY };
    }).flatMap(mouseDownPos => this.mousemove.map(pos => {
      return { x: pos.clientX - mouseDownPos.x, y: pos.clientY - mouseDownPos.y };
    }).takeUntil(this.dragend));
  }
}
```

Take that with a pinch of salt as I am currently chasing a memory leak which seems to be related to this directive. I will update if I find an issue.