# Angular2 / TypeScript - Variable not changed

Tags: typescript, angular

It looks my variable's `isInfinitiveScrollLoaderEnabled` value does not change when reaching bottom of page. If I put it at the beginning `ngOnInit` method, it changes successfully.

What could be wrong?

```
export class SomeClass {
  private isInfinitiveScrollLoaderEnabled: boolean;

  constructor() {
    this.isInfinitiveScrollLoaderEnabled = false;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    window.onscroll = (event) => {
      if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.scrollHeight) {
        console.log('Bottom of page');
        this.isInfinitiveScrollLoaderEnabled = true;
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular provides an easy way to listen to events on `window` or `document`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'some-class',
  // alternative to @HostListener below
  // host: {'(window:scroll)':'onScroll($event')},
  ...
})
export class SomeClass {
  private isInfinitiveScrollLoaderEnabled: boolean;

  constructor() {
    this.isInfinitiveScrollLoaderEnabled = false;
  }

  @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
  onScroll(event) {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.scrollHeight) {
      console.log('Bottom of page');
      this.isInfinitiveScrollLoaderEnabled = true;
    }
  }
}
```

For an imperative way see [Programmatically (un)register to event with Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35314212/programmatically-unregister-to-event-with-angular-2)

Answer (score 2):

You need leverage the `NgZone` class to execute the `onscroll` callback in the context of Angular2 when the event is triggered:

```
export class SomeClass {
  private isInfinitiveScrollLoaderEnabled: boolean;

  constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {
    this.isInfinitiveScrollLoaderEnabled = false;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    window.onscroll = (event) => {
      if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.scrollHeight) {
        console.log('Bottom of page');
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
          this.isInfinitiveScrollLoaderEnabled = true;
        });
      }
    };
  }
}
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/PI5wbMnWEY56EiB4wGEH?p=preview.

It's because the `window` object is instantiated outside Angular2...

Answer (score 1):

Günter Zöchbauer's answer is perfect (upvoted). I want to explain a bit about it:

The Zone library that Angular2 uses internally monkey patches a lot of APIs, including the event listener APIs. But this does not include the window/element `on<EVENT>` properties, maybe because they are considered old and discouraged.

But if you use the `addEventListener` API, this should work just fine.

Example:

```
export class SomeClass {
  private isInfinitiveScrollLoaderEnabled: boolean;

  constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {
    this.isInfinitiveScrollLoaderEnabled = false;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', (event) => {
      if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.scrollHeight) {
        console.log('Bottom of page');
        this.isInfinitiveScrollLoaderEnabled = true;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Of course if you can about abstracting away the DOM for use with server rendering or mobile frameworks like NativeScript / ReactNative, you can go for the other valid options

```
import {DOM} from 'angular2/platform/common_dom.dart';

DOM
    .getGlobalEventTarget('window')
    .addEventListener('message', function, false);
```

Or

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])`
```

which looks the most declarative to me.

Both as Günter Zöchbauer mentioned.

If you don't care about these rendering considerations, they might look foreign or so in your code. It's your call either way and should be fine.

Whatever you choose, I'd stay away from the `this.ngZone.run()` option, because it brings bad memories from the days of `$scope.$apply()`, although admittedly it's not as bad.