# Angular2: Unsubscribe from host listener

Tags: typescript, angular

If I subscribe to an event in an Angular2 component using host{}, how can I unsubscribe from the event?

```
@Component({
    selector: "foo",
    host: {
        "(window:resize)": "doSomething($event)"
    }
});
```

I've tried to use $event to unsubscribe, but the event itself never presents the scenario in which I want to unsubscribe.

For now, I'm just doing a poor man's short circuit, but I'd prefer to avoid the extra checks involved in short circuiting.

**Poor man's short circuit:**

```
private _conditionMet:boolean = false;
doSomething(e) {
    if(this._conditionMet) {
        return;
    }
    ...
}

somethingElse() {
    this._conditionMet = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't unsubscribe from host-listener. If you need to unsubscribe you need to subscribe imperatively.

See also [Programmatically (un)register to event with Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35314212/programmatically-unregister-to-event-with-angular-2/35314254#35314254)